# Unable to put Python code to Joomla

Tags: python, joomla

I have a Python code from Google app engine.
I need to implement it to Joomla.

**How can you implement Python code to Joomla?**

**[edit after the 1st answer]**

It is enough for me that I can put the code to a module position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla is PHP based whereas Google App Engine is Python based (and tends to use Django).  Your best bet is to either find an alternative to the python code, find someone to translate it, or learn python and manually translate it.

There's no straight python to php conversion though.

EDIT: but if you really want to be adventurous, you can try the Python in PHP project which is still early phase and looks to be someone's side project: http://www.csh.rit.edu/~jon/projects/pip/

Comment: The project which you mention is interesting - thank you for letting me to know it! Perhaps, it possible to make a module for Joomla which allows to put Python code to article position. It is enough for me to have the Python code at the module position.

Comment: This is no longer true. AppEngine ships with PHP now, unfortunately joomla doesn't play nicely on it due to read-only file-system environment.