# Can you display python web code in Joomla?

Tags: php, python, joomla, cherrypy, joomla3.0

I'm building a Joomla 3 web site but I have the need to customize quite a few pages. I know I can use PHP with Joomla, but is it also possible to use Python with it? Specifically, I'm looking to use CherryPy to write some custom pieces of code but I want them to be displayed in native Joomla pages  (not just iFrames). Is this possible?

Comment: Do you already have the Joomla site? If you dislike PHP and like Python (I don't blame you), why not use a CMS written in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP execution of Python "scripts"**

This will work for scripts, which do stuff and return the output, not for CherryPy.

```
 <?php
    // execute your Python script from PHP
    $command = escapeshellcmd('myPythonScript.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);

    echo $output;

    // take response content to embed it into the page
 ?>
```

**PHP to access a Python/CherryPy served website**

```
import cherrypy
class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

This starts a `http://localhost:8080` and you should see `Hello world!`.

Now you could access CherryPy's output by accessing it at it's `localhost:port`.
Not good performance-wise, but works.

```
<?php
    $output = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8080/');
    echo $output;
?>
```

**Joomla + Ajax to access a Pyhton/CherryPy served website**

An alternative solution would be, to not use PHP to fetch the content, but to do the fetch from client-side. Basically, you would use an Ajax-Request to the CherryPy served website, to fetch it's content and embed it into the dom of the Joomla served page.

```
 // add jQuery Ajax reqeust from your Joomla page to CherryPy
 $.ajax({
    url: "https://localhost:8080/", // <-- access the 2nd served website
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
      //console.log(res);
      alert(res);
      $("#someElement").html(res);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most efficient way of constructing pages from different sources (Joomla and CherryPy) is probably using Edge Side Includes [esi](/questions/tagged/esi).

Basically you run a Joomla instance that serves the documents that contain ESI tags. You run a CherryPy instance that serves the pieces you want to put on the location of the esi tags. And you run a reverse proxy that supports ESI like varnish to stitch it all together.

That may look like a lot of moving parts, but it will be responsive like... something that is really responsive. Tune the caching parts and you relieve your Joomla and database from a lot of work.

The `exec` way from the other answers will work for small python scripts that print something, but will *not* work for CherryPy.

Comment: There's some discussion related to this here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-framework/-3TU_ab5M3A

Answer (score 0):

You can execute it through a php file. Try this:

```
exec("python/path/your-script.py");
```

Comment: Oh very interesting. Does this also apply to python scripts that output to a web framework like CherryPy? Or how would I make that Python script output web items?

Comment: @JimBeam This will *only* work for processes that print output and exit. As you suspected, CherryPy is a long running process that doesn't print your web content.

Answer (score 0):

> It's possible, but not very efficient.
>
> You can execute a Python script from PHP using the exec() function:
>   PHP Code:
>
> ```
> exec("python /path/to/python-script.py");
> ```
>
> There are also a variety of similar PHP functions that can be used to
>   accomplish the same thing with minor differences to the way input and
>   output are handled (passthru, system, proc_open, backticks).
>
> The Python script will be executed using its command line interface -
>   not using CGI (or similar) interface as you would have if the web
>   server were directly executing the Python script. This means that the
>   Python script will not have access to information about the HTTP
>   request - GET/POST values, the client's IP address, the page URL, etc.
>   You could pass this information from PHP to Python using command line
>   parameters, a pipe, a temporary file or some other form of
>   inter-process communication, but you need to pass each piece of
>   required information explicitly.
>
> The reason this is inefficient is because every call to exec will
>   spawn a whole new process for the Python script. That's a fairly
>   expensive operation to do on every HTTP request (this is why servers
>   like Apache and interfaces like Fast-CGI re-use child processes and
>   threads instead of creating new ones). Additionally, if you have more
>   than one call to exec, every single one is going to spawn a new
>   process.

Extracted from [here](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/embedding-python-code-inside-joomla-941835.html).

More info : [Unable to put Python code to Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718498/unable-to-put-python-code-to-joomla)

Comment: "Unable to put Python code to Joomla" seems to be more about porting a Python webapp to Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

**Before considering Python**

- What are you wanting to customize? (perhaps some clever Javascript or a Joomla extension already exists)
- Is the Joomla-way not a better solution for your problem, given the fact that you're using Joomla? (change the template, or the view-templates of the modules and component in particular)

  i.o.w.: do you understand Joomla *enough* to know that you need something else? See below:

**If Python is still the way to go:**

- Does your hosting support Python?
- Should you reconsider your choice of CMS?

I like your choice of CherryPy.